# How to solve this 4th order ODE with polynomial coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Write the general solution 
>   for $ (x^2) y'''' + (3x^2-2x)y''' + (3x^2-4x+2)y'' +(x^2-2x+2)y' 
>  = 0 $

I tried to **guess** a solution and use the fact that i can decrease the ODE to less power ( to $y'''$ ) by using the Wronskian.

I guessed that $ e^{-x} $ is a solution.

Is it the way we solve this kind of equations? It's a homework question so i guess (i / you) can solve it.

Euler ODE doesn't work here .

> Can you help me with the solutions i got 4 solutions : ( after solving Euler equation and moving to $ v''' $ .

$y'(x) = \{ e^{-x}  ,~  \frac{x^3}{3}e^{-x} ,~ \frac{x^2}{2}e^{-x}   \}$ or any linear combination of those, **uniqueness theorem doesn't apply here near $x=0$**

Comment: Your coefficients are polynomials, so it might be reasonable to assume $y$ takes the form of a polynomial. Else, if you have found a solution (say $y_{1} = e^{-x}$), then you can search for another solution of the form $y_{2} = v(x)e^{-x}$.

Comment: Solution $0$ won't help.  But the constant $1$ is also a solution, and is linearly independent of the others, so it will help.

Comment: true i will integrate all and get a linear Space of those but how can i know that the answer is right its impossible to start puting each one at a time

Comment: not possible to integrate some of them like $ \frac{x^3}{3} e^{-x} $

Comment: Are you familiar with this theorem? https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Liouville-Ostrogradski_formula

Comment: not sure @Zacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the coefficients. You have the sequence $1,3,3,1$ in the quadratic terms, remembering the binomial theorem you get thus $x^2(D+1)^3Dy$, $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. Then in the linear terms coefficients $2,4,2$ which gives you $-2x(D+1)^2Dy$ and similarly for the constant terms, so that
$$
0=[x^2(D+1)^3-2x(D+1)^2+2(D+1)]Dy
$$
which means that you get to solve the factorized system
$$
(D+1)Dy=u,\\
[x^2(D+1)^2-2x(D+1)+2]u=0.
$$
The last equation is an Euler-Cauchy equation for $e^xu$,
$$
[x^2D^2-2xD+2](e^xu)=0.
$$

Comment: not sure what did you do but i got the same unique polynomal equation ! $ (r-1)(r-2) $ and from there i got the semi solutions writing up there after integrating

Comment: Well, then working backwards you get $e^xu=span\{x,x^2\}$, $e^xy'\in span\{1,x^2,x^3\}$, $y\in span\{1,e^{-x},\frac{d^2}{da^2}(e^{ax}/a)|_{a=-1}, \frac{d^3}{da^3}(e^{ax}/a)|_{a=-1}\}$.

Comment: how can one obtain general solution ?

Comment: yes this is what i got without the $1$ how did you find the $ 1 $  in the span , did you guess it ?

Comment: In every integration you get an integration constant. These are the multiples of the constant function with value $1$.

Comment: oh right thanks , just to be clear i said that $ y'(x) = e^{-x}v(x)$  and from there i got that $v(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$ or $v(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}$ . is it the same solution like yours becuase i can't tell , so the solution is $y(x)\in$span{$\int e^{-x}x^2$,$\int e^{-x} x^3$,$e^{-x}$,1}

Comment: Yes, that is the same,  in linear combinations you can push constant factors into the undetermined coefficients. You should not forget $v(x)=1$ as the third solution in $x^2v'''-2xv''+2v'=0$.

Comment: thanks , one last thing you wrote $ \frac{d^{2}}{da^{2}} $ what did you mean by  that , in the span i wrote as an integral over dx and you wrote derivitive $da$ not $dx$

Comment: This integration trick is inspired or taken from the Laplace transform. Notice the $a$ in $e^{ax}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Once you have guessed a solution, namely $y_1(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x}$, set $y=z\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ and obtain an third order equation for $z'$.

Comment: Indeed but is it the the best type of solving this equation , there is no other easy ways to solve this right ?

Comment: You can substitue $$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=v(x)$$ and then use the Laplace transformation

Comment: can you please help out

Comment: i have found 4 solutions using a long way

Comment: do you know a good site to check it out , wolfram doesn't give me a good one , here is my solutions :        {$ e^{-x}$ , $\frac{x^3}{3}e^{-x}$ , $\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-x}$ , $ 0 $}